# laravel collection orderBy method with string value column type

Tags: php, laravel, collections

i use bellow code for sorting some metas but the type of the column value is string so orderBy method sort it like a string ( value = '22')

Code :

```
$metas = Meta::where(['cat' => 'view', 'meta_name' => 'daily'])->orderBy('meta_value', 'desc')->get();
```

so how i sort them base on numeric  value ?
if there isn't any solution in laravel methods please guide is php & mysql

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sortByDesc`. Try the below code:

```
    $metas = Meta::where(['cat' => 'view', 'meta_name' => 'daily'])->get()
             ->sortByDesc(function($value){
                 return (int) $value->meta_value;
             });
```

Answer (score 0):

`Meta::where()->get()` returns a [laravel collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-sort). In case you need a custom sorting you could use a custom sort function which internally uses php's [uasort()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php).

```
Mega::where([..])->get()->sort(function($a, $b) {
    return (int)$a->meta_value <=> (int)$b->meta_value;
})
```